# Troubleshooting Perl CGI app - Can't locate object method "new" via package

Tags: perl, cgi

I have inherited an old perl app that I'm trying to resurrect.  Sadly I'm not a perl guy (and only a novice developer).  I've had some success fixing other problems with this app by finding solutions online, but a solution to this has eluded me so far, so felt it was time to ask for advice.

I have hit a roadblock and looking for advice on how to troubleshoot an error I'm receiving.

This is the error:

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "CGI" at 
/opt/app/htdocs/lib/APP/CGI.pm line 26.Compilation failed 
in require at /opt/app/htdocs/lib/APP/CGI.pm line 4.
```

Here is the first 26 lines of /opt/app/htdocs/lib/APP/CGI.pm:

```
 package APP::CGI;

 use CGI;

 use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser set_message);
 use APP::Error;

 BEGIN {
      sub handle_errors {
         my $msg = shift;
         &APP::Error::error($msg);
     }
     set_message(\&handle_errors);

 }

 use strict;
 # hack:  added these to resolve "can't locate" errors
 use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs);
 use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs/lib);
 use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs/lib/APP);
 use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs/lib/APP/Service);
 # end hack
 use vars qw/ $CGI %REDIRS /;

 $CGI = new CGI();
```

I've been having to add the following to other scripts in the app to make things work (to resolve can't locate errors), so I've added them in this script, but it hasn't resolved the issue.

```
 use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs);
 use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs/lib);
 use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs/lib/APP);
 use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs/lib/APP/Service);
```

My guess is that my app cannot find the CGI module (referenced as "use CGI;" in the snippet).  I have confirmed the CGI module is installed and up-to-date:

```
 cpanm -i CGI
 CGI is up to date. (4.40)
```

Perl Version is 5.26.2, if that matters.

**Any tips on how to troubleshoot?  I feel like this CGI.pm file cannot find the CGI module, which is why it can't execute the method "new"... but it's just a guess.**

Comment: That's not the reason; if it can't find the module, "use" will throw an error which is not what happened here.

Comment: Try changing the `new CGI();` to `CGI->new();`. That type of indirect object syntax was added to Perl when it was trying to be like the cool kids, but it can confuse Perl's interpreter so it's no longer recommended. See this perldoc for more info: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax

Answer (score 6):

```
package APP::CGI;

[…]

use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs/lib);
use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs/lib/APP);
use lib qw(/opt/app/htdocs/lib/APP/Service);
```

These `use lib` lines look really wrong. If this pattern was used in other files as well, it will cause `use CGI` to be resolved to `/opt/lib/htdocs/lib/APP/CGI.pm` (i.e, the file that you're looking at!), not [the standard module](https://metacpan.org/release/CGI) that was intended.

Remove **all** `use lib` lines from Perl modules (`.pm`) in your project. This directive should only appear in top-level Perl scripts (`.pl`, `.cgi`, *etc*); even there, there should only be one `use lib` referring to the `lib` directory of your project, not to any subdirectories.

Comment: I kept hitting an error where the app "can't locate <script> at @INC", so I was using the above to add those directories to @INC (https://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=24911)

Comment: @RedColeman Well, stop doing that, then. Individual modules should not modify `@INC` when loaded, and there should not be multiple entries in `@INC` which reference the same directory tree.

Comment: @Red Coleman, Re "*I kept hitting an error*", So ask a Question about how to properly resolve that problem. I 100% agree with duskwuff's answer

Answer (score 2):

Your `use lib` lines are too over-eager. You are adding a bunch of paths to the beginning of `@INC`, but you need to only add the base directory. `use CGI;` will search `@INC` for the first file it finds by adding `CGI.pm` to the path, this will find `/opt/app/htdocs/lib/APP/CGI.pm` due to the extra paths you added. Obviously, that's not CGI, and doesn't define the CGI package, so there's no `new` method for it to find there. Your lib path is likely just `/opt/app/htdocs/lib`.

Comment: I kept hitting an error where the app "can't locate <script> at @INC", so I was using the above to add those directories to @INC (perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=24911).  Some of the scripts are in /opt/app/htdocs and not /opt/app/htdocs/lib...  I was doing symbolic links, which were working, but I thought the "use lib" was a shortcut.

Comment: `@INC` is for loading modules, not scripts. If you mean you are doing `require 'foo.pl'` or `do 'foo.pl'` to load them from `@INC`, you shouldn't do this; either make them into real modules or pass the absolute path to `do`.